# How to get the Clickstream Data from a Heroku deployed website

Tags: heroku, clickstream

I have a little website which I have it deployed on Heroku. I'm learning Clickstream Data analysis, but I don't know how to get access to the navigation logs on Heroku, that I'll treat on Hadoop. Do I need to install a third-party app? How can I see the logs?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your heroku logs directly in your development environment with:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Alternatively, you can add one of many [Heroku Elements add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=logs) for viewing logs, such as Papertrail.